# Проблема с формой после применения jQuery

Tags: jquery, форма

Есть такая простая проверка заполнены ли поля формы на jQuery, если поле формы не заполнено, оно обводится красной рамкой.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':submit').click(function (e) {
        $(':text, :password').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Но проблема в том, что после внедрения данного jQuery кода, кнопка Submit стала неактивной и я не могу форму передать на обработку php скрипту.

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением данного бага. Заранее благодарен Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':submit').click(function(e){
        var allOk = true;
        $(':text, :password').each(function(){
            var stl = '2px solid ';
            if($(this).val()) {
                stl += 'green';
            } else {
                stl += 'red';
                allOk = false;
            }
            $(this).css('border', stl);
        });
        !allOk && e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

То есть:

1. **e.preventDefault(**) должна вызываться
       только если форма заполнена
       некорректно.
2. Нужно устанавливать
       стиль и для корректно заполненных
       (исправленных) полей формы.